# How to persist http headers in a column in SQlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, webview

what is the most straightforward way to persist response's headers in SQLite?
I am trying to cache a website and then reload it from disk, I save the InputStream in a file, I create a record with the file path, encoding, mimetype and url in the DB, but I realized I needed to persist the response headers as well in order to be able to reconstruct the whole thing later on and return a new `WebResourceResponse` for my webview.
The headers are basically a `Map<String, String>` so how do I most conveniently serialize them to a string to save in the DB and then deserialize them to a Map again?

Comment: "The headers are basically a Map<String, String>" This is because you have parsed the headers with some API. You can persist this map in some form, such as JSON or you can persist the raw headers as a string.

Comment: good idea. am I right to assume that I have to persist the headers and reattach them again later? or are they included in the inputstream of the connection? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Try reading directly from the connection and see what you get.

Comment: I get weird behavior and I've tried all I could think of, so it came to this :)

Comment: Then you need to edit this question or post a new one to include a [mcve] to show what you are doing.